# How i can translate article in codeigniter? the localization work on the app but not on thes artclles

Tags: codeigniter, localization, multilingual

I would like to know how I can `translate` the articles according to the language of the user ! the language set on the app when the user changes the language, the article must be translated also, localization is already set up in the app but not on the article! i should use an `API` for that or i can do it without? please tell me!

NB: I got only access via `FTP` so, I can install packages via `composer`! 
please show me some example or link!

how I can use packages in `Codeigniter` without use composer, like download it directly from `GitHub` an put it in my project!

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in your website structure:

HTML Code:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

This is for your whole website will be translated, I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Kishan , but i want do it automaticaly ,can i do it with php instead?

Comment: i want save the articles in different languages in the database!

Comment: You need to add language type in your table of the database and collation of the article column should be "utf8_general_ci". And read carefully the docs of the CodeIgniter language class from https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html